# jQuery validate and ASP.NET MVC not displaying error messages

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I'm working with ASP.NET MVC 5 and jQuery unobtrusive form field validation.

I've got the web.config setting set correctly.

If I don't fill in a required field, I cannot submit the form and the cursor is set to the empty field.

However, no error message is displayed.

Razor:

```
<div class="d-1of2 t-1of2 m-all">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FirstName)
                    @Html.MaxLengthTextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName, new { @class = "alphaonly" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FirstName)
                </div>
```

Model:

```
        [Required]
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
```

Markup (from "View Page Source"):

```
<div class="d-1of2 t-1of2 m-all">
    <label for="FirstName">First Name</label>
    <input class="alphaonly" data-val="true" data-val-length="The field First Name must be a string with a maximum length of 100." data-val-length-max="100" data-val-required="The First Name field is required." id="FirstName" maxlength="100" name="FirstName" type="text" value="" />
    <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="FirstName" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
</div>
```

So, it looks like the unobtrusive stuff is all in place for things to work.

When I debug the jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js file, the problem is in this function:

```
    function onError(error, inputElement) {  // 'this' is the form element
    var container = $(this).find("[data-valmsg-for='" + escapeAttributeValue(inputElement[0].name) + "']"),
        replaceAttrValue = container.attr("data-valmsg-replace"),
        replace = replaceAttrValue ? $.parseJSON(replaceAttrValue) !== false : null;

    container.removeClass("field-validation-valid").addClass("field-validation-error");
    error.data("unobtrusiveContainer", container);

    if (replace) {
        container.empty();
        error.removeClass("input-validation-error").appendTo(container);
    }
    else {
        error.hide();
    }
}
```

The variable "replaceAttrValue" is "undefined" because container.attr("data-valmsg-replace") is 'undefined'.  But, that element and that data attribute appear to be present.

Has anyone seen this before?  I'm obviously missing something, but what?